# Gtk3: GMenu/GMenuItem: How to sense if a submenu was opened? ( signal of submenus)

Tags: c, menu, gtk, gtk3, submenu

My application has an "Edit" menu in the top bar. I want to change the sensitivity (enabled / disabled) and visibility of it's content when the menu opens.

I'm using GMenu / GMenuItem to create the menu.
How do I sense, when the submenu was opened?

Remarks:

- I don't want to use GtkMenu (because of deprecation)
- I checked GMenu for signals, but is has none.

#### How I create my menu:

```
{
  GMenu * menubar = g_menu_new();

  GMenu * edit = g_menu_new();
  g_menu_append_submenu(menubar,"_Edit", G_MENU_MODEL(edit));

  g_menu_append(edit, "_Copy" ,   "edit.copy"   );    
  g_menu_append(edit, "_Paste",   "edit.paste"  );    
       
  gtk_application_set_menubar(app, G_MENU_MODEL(menubar));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the attribute **submenu-action**. This will not give you an "on-open" callback, but an "on-open" OR "on-close" callback. But it's probably the closest you can get.

## Use it from a menu file:

[Here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/blob/gtk-3-24/examples/bp/gtk/menus.ui#L88) is an example of how you would use it within a ui file:

```
<submenu id="time-menu">
  <attribute name="label" translatable="yes">Time</attribute>
  <attribute name="submenu-action">app.time-active</attribute>
</submenu>
```

## Use it from the API

Using it from the API is a little tricky: You need to create a GMenuItem, that holds your `GMenu * edit` as submenu.

#### Architecture:

```
GMenu (menubar)
   |
   |-- GMenuItem ("Edit" (edit_item))  <-- new part
          |
          |-- GMenu (edit_content)
                 |
                 |-- GMenuItem ("Copy") 
                 |
                 |-- GMenuItem ("Paste")
```

#### Example code

```
{
  GMenu * menubar = g_menu_new ();

  // Container for all menu items of the "Edit" menu
  GMenu * edit_content = g_menu_new ();
  {
    g_menu_append (edit_content, "_Copy" ,   "edit.copy" );    
    g_menu_append (edit_content, "_Paste",   "edit.paste");    
  }

  // create the "Edit" menu button, that has an "on-click" event
  GMenuItem * edit_menu;
  {
    edit_menu = g_menu_item_new ("Edit", "randomAction"); // (the action will be discarded later)
    // set action, that's fired up on click
    g_menu_item_set_attribute (edit_menu,"submenu-action", "&s", 
                                "app.menu_edit_clicked", NULL);      
    // insert the content of menu
    g_menu_item_set_submenu (edit_menu, G_MENU_MODEL (edit_content));      
    // add it to window
    g_menu_append_item (menubar, edit_menu);

    // set the on-click action(s) for the submenu
    GActionEntry actions[] = {
      {.name="menu_edit_clicked", .state="false", 
       .change_state=dt_window_menu_on_click}
    };
    g_action_map_add_action_entries (G_ACTION_MAP (app), actions, G_N_ELEMENTS (actions), NULL);
  }

  gtk_application_set_menubar (app, G_MENU_MODEL (menubar));


  g_object_unref (menubar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't typically change the visibility/sensitivity of GMenu items when the menu opens; you always change the GAction state depending on your internal state, and that will update the visibility/sensitivity of the GMenu, which will update the state of the widgets.

Actions are the model; menus are the controllers; and the widgets that are implicitly created by GTK are the views.

Comment: "You don't typically change the visibility/sensitivity...": I wonder how "typically" is defined. Other behaviors put an unnecessary burden on the machine. Why should something be updated, that is only rarely used. But I understand that the system is not particularly designed to use it that way.

Comment: The basic design is that your application state changes will update the actions that are bound to that state; if UI is not visible, changes to it won't cause any further work to be scheduled anyway. On the contrary, doing work when the UI is visible, like changing the state of the menus while the menu is being opened, might very well delay the user action.

Comment: if menu updating is a slowing down process opening the menu will indeed delay the user. But that would be only once every open. Not every click within the app.

Comment: Updating the internal state of your application shouldn't slow down your application; and if it does, it's entirely constrained within your application. Querying the state of the application every time you open a menu, while you're opening it, on the other hand, has repercussions across layers of the stack that you don't control. As a general tenet for GUI applications: you should follow a model/view split, with your business logic updating the UI whenever needed, not at forced synchronisation points.

Comment: Isnt this exaclty what I'm trying to achieve? "update the UI whenever needed". It only needs updating, if it's going to be shown. If I get you right, you're expressing, that a value, that is needed once every 1000 clicks should be updated every (of the 1000) clicks.